# Where to put HTML email template

Tags: 2010

I am going to customize the request access functionality by changing the application page it must use with a Powershell script.
What the users want is an easy way to change the emails with HTML.

Where can I put that HTML template to be easily editable? 
I was thinking that in the property bag I could put a path to an HTML file on site pages? or what other suggestions would u have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I often use this way - you can create a list with rich text column and store your HTML there. Ypu can save it via "Edit source HTML" option in Ribbon. So your users will be able to easily edit HTML template in visual editor and you'll be able to easily get it programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

If they would like to edit it using SharePoint tools, I would probably consider creating a "configuration" list somewhere in SharePoint, and add one item with Rich Text field.